# python 3 как подставить переменную в строку без кавычек

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

мне нужно подставить переменную в строку без кавычек:

```
self.__{key} = value
```

Если что вот вся функция:

```
def setItem(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.__{key} = value
```

Comment: а где здесь у вас лишние кавычки добавляются?  приведите пример вызова, результат и что хотелось бы получить

Comment: @splash58 я имел ввиду что есть например переменные: self.__tea, self.__pizza, self.__cookies                           
и мне нужно подставить название переменной после self.__

Comment: @andreymal с двумя подчеркиваниями так не выйдет - имя переменной строится иначе

Comment: @splash58 действительно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в случае, если имя переменной начинается с двух подчеркиваний, python, по крайней мере 3.8, строит имя переменной в словаре иначе, добавляя в начало имя класса. Я привел ниже вывод словаря.

```
 class A :
    def setItem(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__['_'+self.__class__.__name__+'__'+key] = value

     print(self.__dict__)    # {'_A__tea': 'sdfsdf', '_A__soup': 'asd'}           

     print(self.__tea)       # sdfsdf

a = A()
a.setItem(tea='sdfsdf', soup='asd')
```

Если же использовать не "приватные" переменные, то действительно можно просто сделать `setattr(self, "_" + key, value)`. Так работает для "публичных" и "защищенных" переменных

Comment: Спасибо  большое, все работает!

Comment: @Smile куда $ оно денется :) Удачи!