# Убрать ограничение доступа к private и protected атрибутам pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, инкапсуляция

В `python` ограничение доступа к атрибутам остаётся на совести программиста, но `pycharm` по умолчанию запрещает доступ извне к атрибутам с префиксом `__` или `_` в именах.

Если я сделаю так

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = 5

mc = MyClass()
print(mc.__data)
```

То `pycharm` не выдаёт поле `__data` в подсказках и подчеркивает поле `__data` в записи с `print` с предупреждением **Unresolved attribute reference '__data' for class 'MyClass'**.

Если я запущу этот код, то выскочет ошибка **AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__data'**.

Как настроить `pycharm` чтобы она не ограничивала доступ извне к атрибутам с префиксами `__` `_` в имени и код из примера спокойно работал?

Comment: неправда ваша, почитайте, как питон именует  такие атрибуты в словаре объекта

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [python 3 как подставить переменную в строку без кавычек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278310/python-3-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba)

Comment: @splash58 и правда, написал `print(mc._MyClass__data)`, заработало. Всегда думал что это пайчарм что-то ограничивает. Правда пайчарм всё равно подчёркивает строку с `print`, но это даже правильно, обращение к приватным полям нежелательно.